# Django - Gunicorn won't run/Worker fails to boot

Tags: django, python-3.x, nginx, wsgi, gunicorn

I've been following the Digital Ocean tutorial on setting up Django with nginx and Gunicorn. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 3.4.

I'm at the Gunicorn step and the "gunicorn projectsyfa.wsgi:application " command is not working. I'm at a lost of what to do.

Running it in /home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/projectsyfa just stalls. No error message or anything. It's like it's trying to do something, but I'd sit there for awhile and nothing will come up.

Running it in /home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/projectsyfa/projectsyfa gives me

```
Exception in worker process:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'projectsyfa.wsgi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 502, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 114, in init_process
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 66, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 356, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named 'projectsyfa.wsgi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/gunicorn", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('gunicorn==19.0.0', 'console_scripts', 'gunicorn')()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 74, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 166, in run
    super(Application, self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 71, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 169, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 477, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 537, in spawn_workers
    time.sleep(0.1 * random.random())
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 209, in handle_chld
    self.reap_workers()
  File "/home/ubuntu/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 459, in reap_workers
    raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
```

My directories look like:

```
/home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/projectsyfa/projectsyfa# ls
__init__.py  __pycache__  settings.py  urls.py  wsgi.py


/home/ubuntu/myenv/bin/projectsyfa# ls
manage.py  projectsyfa
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Django 3.4 only runs on Ubuntu 21.08 or later.

Comment: Whoops, I meant Python 3.4, I'm using Django 1.6.5... Which I guess means I need 1.7

Comment: I've updated to 1.7 rc. I'm getting the same problem (assuming I don't have to delete my project and start over)